# Get all parent that have child's jpa spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Job Entity I have =>

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("job")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "job")
private List<Reject> reject;
```

and Reject Entity I have =>

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "job_id")
private Job job;

private String cause;
```

I need to get the jobs that have reject

I can achieve that when I use custom query like this

```
 @Query("SELECT DISTINCT j FROM Job j JOIN FETCH j.reject")
 Page<Job> findByRejectIdIsNotNull(Pageable pageable);
```

but I need it without custom query

I tried do (findByRejectIsNotNull , findByRejectIsNotEmpty ) but its not work

Get all jobs that have reject.

Comment: Why you need it without  custom query?

Comment: *but its not work* is not an error description. Explain what i not working

Comment: @Jens
`findByRejectIdIsNotNull` its get  all jobs that have and dont have reject

Comment: @Jens
I just need to know if there is any way to do it wihout custom query